# How can I connect a .net application to read a stream from a Delta table in Azure Databricks?

Tags: .net, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

How can I write e.g. a console application in .Net that would read a delta table or open a stream to a delta table in Azure Databricks.

I've tried this code

```
var spark = SparkSession
    .Builder()
    .AppName("Streaming example with a UDF")
    .Config("spark.databricks.service.address", "https://adb-somenumericid.azuredatabricks.net/")
    .Config("spark.databricks.service.token", "mypat")
    .Config("spark.databricks.service.clusterId", "0118-xxxxx-yyyyyy")
    .Config("spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled", true)
    .GetOrCreate();

var table = spark.Read().Format("delta").Table("mycatalog.mydb.mytable");
table.Show();
```

but I get the error

> [MSF002237] [Exception] [JvmBridge] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 127.0.0.1:5567

How can I get the code to connect to my Databricks cluster instead of localhost?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue with below code:

```
using Microsoft.Spark.Sql;

SparkSession spark = SparkSession.Builder()
    .AppName("Read Delta table in .NET")
    .Config("spark.databricks.service.address", "https://<databricksID>.azuredatabricks.net")
    .Config("spark.databricks.service.token", "<AccessToken>")
    .GetOrCreate();

   
DataFrame deltaTable = spark.Read()
    .Format("delta")
    .Table("hive.warehouse.empp");


deltaTable.Show();
```

I got the same error:

[image]

I followed below procedure to resolve the issue.

I installed .net core SDK  and set the path of .net core sdk in environment variables and install java and set path for java and downloaded apache spark and extract the files into `C:\bin\spark` and set below environment variables HADOOP_HOME with `C:\bin\spark`, SPARK_HOME with `C:\bin\spark` Path with `C:\bin\spark` . Installed Microsoft worker and installed to `C:\bin\runner` set that that path as environment variable. I checked for confirmation of spark by using

```
spark-submit --version
```

I got below output:

[image]

I downloaded and installed the winutils to the spark path. I created run the console applicaton by using below format in the console app path in command prompt

```
spark-submit.cmd --class org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner --master local <jarpath>\mrosoft-spark-2-4_2.11-<version>.jar dotnet sparkconsole.dll
```

It executed without any error. For more information you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/spark/tutorials/get-started?tabs=windows) and you can follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZIQiBPHAJg).